# How to change domain of href

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have one project with one domain and another project with a different domain.  I want to have a button on the first project which links to the second project.  How can I accomplish this? I currently only know how to change the controller and action with an href

Answer (score 2):

There are no built-in helpers allowing you to generate links across different ASP.NET projects. The url helpers are intended to be used only for generating links to internal controller actions. ASP.NET routing works only for the current project.

You will have to use an absolute url or write custom helpers that could for example use some base url that you would configure in your web.config that will be concatenated with the actual relative url you need to reach.